# No 'webgl' context in Chrome 52

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

This is a pretty baffling issue to me: one of my projects (using three.js) suddenly stopped working. Turns out, calling `document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl')` now inexplicably returns `null`. It works fine in other browsers, but Chrome is completely unable to get a WebGL context. I haven't fiddled with any flags regarding WebGL, and I've tried resetting all flags and disabling extensions as well to get the same result. For reference, I'm running Chrome 52.0.2743.82.

Comment: I'm using the same version of Chrome and running `document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');` in my console returns `WebGLRenderingContext {canvas: canvas, drawingBufferWidth: 300, drawingBufferHeight: 150}`. If you run it in your console via another website, e.g. example.com, does it work?

Comment: Yes, I'm surprised I didn't think to check that actually. I imagine it's an issue with three.js crashing the context, then. I'll do further investigation in a bit.